# jq: select only scalars in objects in JSON array?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON data structure I'd like to filter using `jq`:

```json
{
 "data": [
  {
   "id": "blah",
   "foo": "bar",
   "array": [ ... ]
  },
  {
   "id": "blah",
   "foo": "bar"
   "array": [ ... ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to map this to an array of objects with only the top-level scalar values present in each modified object (i.e. keys containing values like arrays and objects should disappear—I'm not interested in the contents of anything nested here):

```json
[
  {
   "id": "blah",
   "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
   "id": "blah",
   "foo": "bar"
  }
]
```

This should be possible using some combination of `jq`'s `map` and `select` operators in tandem with `scalars`, but I am unable to figure out an exact solution. I expect the answer to be embarrassingly simple. For example, I have tried `.data[] | map(select(scalars))`, etc.

I am using the latest version of `jq`.

Comment: Shouldn't the array also produce some scalars (somewhere deep down)?

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify I am only interested in top-level scalars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with_entries` builtin lets you select upon the value while retaining the object-field structure.

```sh
jq '.data | map(with_entries(select(.value | scalars)))'
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": "blah",
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
    "id": "blah",
    "foo": "bar"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Tu9rFEBysy)

Comment: Excellent, knowledge of `with_entries` is what I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
[.data[] | to_entries | map(select(.value | scalars)) | from_entries]
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/Y7-_8J-DFt

Which is the same as

```
[.data[] | with_entries(select(.value | scalars))]
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/ZjMBXMYeBC